# How to validate tags in xhtml against a facelet-taglib

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces, taglib

What I'm trying to do is write a maven plugin that will validate xhtml files so if any of the tags have attributes that don't belong, are misspelled or if there are any other kind of validation errors, the build will fail.

We are using Primefaces 6.0 and we'd like to include validation of those tags. Problem is that within the Primefaces jar file I can only find a facelet-taglib file (for Primefaces 6.0 in folder META-INF/primefaces-p.taglib.xml) and I don't know how to validate an xhtml file against a facelet-taglib file.

I know how to write Java code to validate using schema files but I haven't had any luck finding any Java examples of validating tags in my xhtml file against a facelet-taglib, specifically the Primefaces taglib xml taglib file.

I have tried loading the taglib file like below...

```
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
InputStream stream = ..[file primefaces-p.taglib.xml]..;
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new StreamSource(stream));
```

But I just get the following error:

*org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 39; s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'http://primefaces.org/ui'.*

I figured maybe I'm using the wrong XMLConstants variable, but I'm not sure which one to use, or if this would even work.

One other note, I am aware of the existing XML Maven Plugin, but I could not get it to work with the primefaces facelet-taglib. If someone knows how to get it to work with the taglib, please let us know!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Taglibs are not schema's so that just won't work. But a descent IDE will use the taglibs for you to do similar validations but in a different way

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It would help to be able to validate within the IDE, but the ultimate goal is to be able to run validation during a Maven build.